# NoClassDefFoundError in simple test

Tags: java, object-object-mapping

I want to use moo for dto- entity conversion. But testing it i get this exception

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mvel2/PropertyAccessException
    at com.codiform.moo.configuration.Configuration.getTranslator(Configuration.java:62)
    at com.codiform.moo.session.TranslationSession.getTranslator(TranslationSession.java:131)
    at com.codiform.moo.session.TranslationSession.translate(TranslationSession.java:122)
    at com.codiform.moo.session.TranslationSession.getTranslation(TranslationSession.java:64)
    at com.codiform.moo.curry.Translate.from(Translate.java:63)
    at Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mvel2.PropertyAccessException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 6 more
```

Is it because i am doing something wrong? Here is my code:

```
import com.codiform.moo.curry.Translate;


public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
Guld guld1=new Guld("string from guld", "muck around", 5);
GuldDTO guld1DTO;
GuldDTO testclassload = new GuldDTO("ruks","halim",3);

guld1DTO=Translate.to(GuldDTO.class).from(guld1);
        //Beca beca1 = new Beca ()

System.out.println(guld1);
System.out.println(guld1DTO);
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Guld {

    private String fielk1;
    private String rupo;
    private Integer higs;
    public Guld(){

    }
    public Guld(String fielk1, String rupo, Integer higs) {

        this.fielk1 = fielk1;
        this.rupo = rupo;
        this.higs = higs;
    }
    public String getFielk1() {
        return fielk1;
    }
    public void setFielk1(String fielk1) {
        this.fielk1 = fielk1;
    }
    public String getRupo() {
        return rupo;
    }
    public void setRupo(String rupo) {
        this.rupo = rupo;
    }
    public Integer getHigs() {
        return higs;
    }
    public void setHigs(Integer higs) {
        this.higs = higs;
    }


}
```

---

```
public class GuldDTO {
    private String fielk1;
    private String rupo;
    private Integer higs;
    public GuldDTO (){

    }
    public GuldDTO(String fielk1, String rupo, Integer higs) {

        this.fielk1 = fielk1;
        this.rupo = rupo;
        this.higs = higs;
    }
    public String getFielk1() {
        return fielk1;
    }
    public void setFielk1(String fielk1) {
        this.fielk1 = fielk1;
    }
    public String getRupo() {
        return rupo;
    }
    public void setRupo(String rupo) {
        this.rupo = rupo;
    }
    public Integer getHigs() {
        return higs;
    }
    public void setHigs(Integer higs) {
        this.higs = higs;
    }

}
```

If there are any other details  i should provide please tell. [Apparently  i cannot get past a stackoverflow filter  that checks for the code to text ratio.][Done]

Comment: Your code has a dependency on the `org.mvel2.PropertyAccessException` class, packaged in  [this jar](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/mvel/mvel2/2.0RC1/mvel2-2.0RC1.jar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ClassNotFoundException excption means class is missing add library for this class and run again.
First check that your apllication has this class or not else add mvel lib.

available at: http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mvel/mvel2/2.1.4.Final/

Comment: Thanks i wasn't using maven and somehow i was expecting that moo has all dependencies included. Plus i never heard of mvel so i thought it was part of Moo and not a reused component

Answer (score 0):

You see the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` when you have a dependency on that class and it's not in your dependency list of your project.

So, what you need to do is:

*add the jar of `org.mvel2.PropertyAccessException` class to your project externally*

The jar is available [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/mvel/mvel2/2.0RC1/mvel2-2.0RC1.jar).

Answer (score 0):

as others have already said above, you are missing a class file and you need to add the required jar file in your `classpath`. In order to check how and where classes are getting loaded you can pass `-verbose:class` to `java` exe. This will show the trace of classes getting loaded as the program runs. Useful for debugging such issues.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, i do not have enough rep to vote up/down